Files shared with me are not visible in my OneDrive account
Someone shared a folder with me through their OneDrive acct. Basically it worked, but not completely, or the way I'm expecting.
The link I was sent via email works: clicking opens OneDrive to the folder and I see everything.
But that shared folder does not show up in my account's Shared list.
Maybe the process of sharing must be done differently but I don't know what must be done differently.

I've logged in and out and it doesn't show up in my account's Shared list
I waited a long time, over a day for syncing
I've checked a dozen other questions with a similar issue

There doesn't seem to be an answer to this.
One thing I noticed is that my account's shared files have a url like this:
https://onedrive.live.com/?id=root&cid=58...D3&qt=sharedby
but the link from the email goes to
https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21As...YY&id=5E...B0%2110...41&cid=5E...B0
There's something different about how this share works (shared by email) that won't let it show up in my account's shared list. The only way to access it is through the button/link in the email. I don't want to have to save the email indefinitely, I'd like it show up in my Shared area.
MS Office 365 Family on both ends.

If the author sent you a link, then anyone who has that link is able to access the shared folders/files. In order to show up in your "shared with you" folder, the author must share it with you OneDrive user name when setting up the share.

Additionally, if the author sent it to you via email address (from within OneDrive share - not as a separate email from their email provider), the email address would need to be associated with your OneDrive account. If they simply copied the link and then sent you the link via their email provider, OneDrive would not know this and thus could not associate it with your OneDrive account.

Ah ha. I think you're on to it. Almost definitely the wrong email/acct. I will check on this.

Crazy. The email was changed to the OneDrive acct's email and the links showed up. Thanks a lot.
